# Соединение динамической кнопки с классом MainWindow ( QT )

Tags: qt, сигналы-слоты, обработка-сигналов

Недавно изучаю qt в QtCreator. В классе MainWindow (главного окна) вызываются виджеты, которые его меняют. В одном из виджетов реализовано динамическое создание кнопок.

> Как соединить динамическую кнопку из функции класса Topics в Main
>   Window? Или как обратиться из функции в Topics к функции из MainWindow?

С обычными кнопками проблем нет, они работают.

Динамическое создание кнопок убрать нельзя, потому что неизвестно заранее количество ( данные берутся из текстового файла)

> mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStackedWidget>

#include <QDebug>
#include <topics.h>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QStackedWidget *stackedWidget;
private:
    Topics *topics;
public slots:
    void toTask();
    void toMain();
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

> mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    topics = new Topics;


    stackedWidget = new QStackedWidget;
    stackedWidget->addWidget(topics);

    stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);

    setCentralWidget(stackedWidget);

    //соединение от topics
    connect(topics->butMain, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(toMain()));//обычная кнопка
    //**connect(topics->butTopic, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(toTask())); // динамическая кнопка здесь ошибка**

}

    void MainWindow::toTask(){
        qDebug() << "dynamic";
    }

    void MainWindow::toMain()
    {
        qDebug() << "main";
    }
```

> topics.h

```
#ifndef TOPICS_H
#define TOPICS_H

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGridLayout >
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QWidget>

#include <QDebug>

class Topics : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Topics(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    QPushButton *butMain;
    QPushButton *butTopic;
private:

    QListWidgetItem *itemTheme;
    QListWidget *lstWgt;
    QGridLayout  *layout;


    void makeItem(QListWidget* lW);
    QLayout* l;
    QWidget* wgt;

private slots:
    void onClicked();
};

#endif // TOPICS_H
```

> topics.cpp

```
#include "topics.h"

Topics::Topics(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    lstWgt = new QListWidget(this);
    itemTheme = new QListWidgetItem();
    layout = new QGridLayout;
    QString str;

    //Кнопки
    butMain = new QPushButton(tr("Главное меню"));

    layout->addWidget(butMain,0,9,1,1);
    itemTheme->setSizeHint(QSize(0,65));

    for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
            makeItem( lstWgt );
        }

    layout->addWidget(lstWgt);
    setLayout(layout);
}
//динамическое создание ТЕМ (кнопка)
void Topics::makeItem(QListWidget *lW)
{
    //я знаю название темы, могу добавить номер темы
    wgt = new QWidget;
    l = new QHBoxLayout;

    butTopic = new QPushButton;
    butTopic->setText("TEXT");
    **connect( butTopic, SIGNAL( clicked() ), SLOT( onClicked() ) );**

    l->addWidget( butTopic );
    wgt->setLayout(l);
    QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem( lW );
    item->setSizeHint( wgt->sizeHint() );
    lW->setItemWidget( item, wgt );
}
void Topics::onClicked()
{
    //нужно знать какая кнопка поэтому использую данную конструкцию
    if( QPushButton* btn = qobject_cast< QPushButton* >( sender() ) ) {
    qDebug() << "вызов из класса";
    }
}
```

main.cpp стандартный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привожу необходимые изменения на скорую руку. Можно было сделать чуть по другому. Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте.

Добавляем новый слот в класс `Topics`:

```
class Topics : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
//Ваш код без изменения

signals:
    void clickedOneOfTheButtons(); //Изменил тут
};
```

Транслируем этот сигнал в `Topics::onClicked()`:

```
void Topics::onClicked()
{
    //нужно знать какая кнопка поэтому использую данную конструкцию
    if( QPushButton* btn = qobject_cast< QPushButton* >( sender() ) ) {
    qDebug() << "вызов из класса";
    emit clickedOneOfTheButtons(); //Изменил тут
    }
}
```

Соединяем этот сигнал в `MainWindow`:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    //Ваш код без изменения

    connect(topics, SIGNAL(clickedOneOfTheButtons()), this, SLOT(toTask())); // Изменил тут
}
```

Как вариант, можно обойтись без `Topics::onClicked()`, соединяя сигнал `clicked()` каждой кнопки непосредственно с сигналом `clickedOneOfTheButtons`.

Можно, также, использовать сигнал `clickedOneOfTheButtons` с аргументами (например текст кнопки, но можно и что-то более значимое, зависит от задачи и вашей фантазии), тогда и `MainWindow::toTask()` надо сделать с той же сигнатурой

PS В приведенном коде подразумевается, что в строке `**connect( butTopic, SIGNAL( clicked() ), SLOT( onClicked() ) );**`никаких звездочек нет

---

Офтоп: Привет Ташкенту!